# PKCS#11 certificates from remote service

Tags: c, cryptography, certificate, pkcs#11

I have a requirement where a PKCS#11 module should retrieve the certificates from remote service (a web service). This service provides a list of certificates based on input parameters passed to a service method.

Is there any possibility to achieve this using an open PKCS#11 module? Or do I have to customize the existing PKCS#11 module implementation to achieve this? I am newbie on PKCS#11 side.

Comment: With only [tag:pkcs11] and [tag:pkcs#11] your question had a snowballs chance in hell of being noticed.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#11 is a C-level interface to handle secure tokens. Now such a token may contain a trust store, for sure, but that's not the main raison d'être for PKCS#11. The main reason is to provided an interface for handling secure keys and algorithms within a secure token. Neither would you expect the data of a PKCS#11 module to be situated at a remote location.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to implement only a small part of PKCS#11 (implement the interface, but let everything return an error) and then implement either a local or remote certificate store. If you implement the local one, you'll have import the certificates into it using some local service that retrieves the certificates.